# how do I get my navigation menu sub items and sub sub items to be underneath each other

Tags: html, css, parent, navbar

Hi I was just wondering if you could help me on how to get my sub menu items and sub sub menu items to be underneath each other instead of to the side of each other, maintaining all other elemnts and stuff. Help would be great, its quite important

here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/7nm7H/

```
    <html>
<head>
<style>
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu, ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 9pt;
}
ul#navmenu li {
width: 202px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
margin-right: 0px;
display:inline-block;
}
#navmenu ul {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
white-space:nowrap;
}
#page1 {
text-align: center;
}
ul#navmenu a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
width: 202px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 25px;
background-color: #2E2E2E;
border: 1px solid #777777;
border-top: 2px solid #777777;
color: white;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-face: Arial;
float: left;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;

}
ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
margin-top: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
margin-left: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
background-color: grey;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {
background-color: red;
}
ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu ul.sub2 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
display: block;
}
ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover .sub2 {
display: block;
}
.darrow {
font-size: 8pt;
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
right: 1px;
}
#navmenu {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;

}
.rarrow {
font-size: 8pt;
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
right: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu {
width:100% !important;
}
#page1 .link1 {
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
border-left: 0px solid red;
}
#page2 .link2 {
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
border-left: 0px solid red;
}
#page3 .link3 {
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
border-left: 0px solid red;
}
.container {
width: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
max-width: 1440px;
height: 1000px;
margin: 0px auto;
white-space: nowrap;
}
#box2 {
height: 1000px;
width: 1024px;
background-color: #FFFE8E;
align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
}
#boxinbox1 {
width: 100%;

background-color: #E51837;
}
</style>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#E51837">

    <div id="box2">
        <div id="page1">
            <div id="boxinbox1"><img src="Logo1.gif"  height="200px">                                      .              <br>                    <img src="text.gif" height="100px"></div>
            <ul id="navmenu">
                <li><a href="dropdown1.html" class="link1">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="dropdown2.html" class="link2">hyperlink 2</a>         .     .            <font color="white">
 <span class="darrow">&#9660;</font>
                    </span>
                    <ul class="sub1">
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 3</a>
                </li>
                 <li> <a href="#">hyperlink 4</a><span class="darrow">                   .       <font color="white">&#9660;               

      </font></span> 
                    <ul class="sub1">
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3</a><span class="rarrow">
  <font color="white">&#9654;</font></span>

                            <ul class="sub2">
                                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3.1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3.2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
<a href="dropdown3.html" class="link3">hyperlink 4.3.3</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 5</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

don't worry about the navbar elements being together or squished, I can fix that up later,

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display:block` css property in all list element

which you want to show underneath. here is the sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/7nm7H/1/

In css part at the end.

Comment: thanks alot its great all I havwe to do now is fix up sub items and arrows :)

Comment: Any time! we are here to help! If you need more help in designing message me!